# whats the actually problem in this code everytime shows msg box on button click. 

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

How to fix the error in code..this code will always display msg box if user select ot nt slect the checkbox ..

but i want if user doesn't select any of the checkbox or forgot to select checkbox then msg box will ppear other wise redirect to other page ..

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />

    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick ="ConfirmSelection(this.form)" Text="Button" />


    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function ConfirmSelection(frm) 
{ 
   for (i=0; i<=1; i++) {
     //chkSubjectOfInterest is the id of your checkbox control

     if (frm.elements[i].name.indexOf('chkSubjectOfInterest') !=-1) 
     { 
       if (frm.elements[i].checked) 
       { 
         return true
       } 
     } 
   } 
   alert('You havent selected an Item yet!')
   return false
}
</script>
```

Comment: or where is chkSubjectOfInterest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that your checkbox names aren't coming out as you expect. I created a fiddle of your code (http://jsfiddle.net/wbzEH/) and just tweaked it to get rid of the serverside code. I also put explicit names into the checkboxes and it works fine.

Are you setting the checkbox names on the server somewhere or have you just forgotten about them?

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just use this?

```
if (document.getElementById('<%=CheckBox1.ClientID%>').checked)
{
// do something
}
```

Or

```
if (document.getElementById('<%=CheckBox2.ClientID%>').checked)
{
// do something
}
```

Comment: That would be a good way of doign it certainly. If he has programatically created 200 checkboxes though then you don't want to write the code for each of them separately... On the other hand using an array to store IDs and a loop or something would probably work well.

Comment: Of course if there is a huge list then this would be no good. Just seemed simpler to me, if it remains as 2 checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

"chkSubjectOfInterest" doesn't correspont to any check box on your page??

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery and try using the classes of your elements rather than the IDs. [Using JQuery to Show/Hide controls depending on Dropdown list selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839222/using-jquery-to-show-hide-controls-depending-on-dropdown-list-selected-value/4840529#4840529)